# ListView.SelecctedItems shows 0 selected

Tags: c#-4.0

ok..Let me explain in better way My requirement is simple as it comes in windows my computer explorer which shows on left the tree node control with folders listing on the right side it shows respected files in it.. the similar way i have already the Tree node control and Listview control implemented. what i need is i will select one node and one object in list view then i click a button in another form it Listview.Selecteditems is showing 0..how to overcome? What i feel it showing 0 bcoz the list view is losing focus Thnx

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd need to provide more details, code excrept will be helpfult too :-)

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to help you, you need to elaborate on what you want so that first of all we can understand what you want, and mean, and then what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say Form1 and Form2 are two classes. then create an object of Form2 in Form1.

In the click event of button try this.

```
//Open the Form2
//Make the Label/TextBox where you want to display the listbox value visible
_Form2Object.LabelName.Text = ListBox1.SelectedValue
```

Hope this helps.

Try providing better explaination or code snippet, so that you can be served better.

Comment: ok..Let me explain in better way
My requirement is simple as it comes in windows my computer explorer
which shows on left the tree node control with folders listing on the right side it shows respected files in it..

the similar way i have already the Tree node control and Listview control implemented. what i need is i will select one node and one object in list view then i click a button in another form it Listview.Selecteditems is showing 0..how to overcome?

What i feel it showing 0 bcoz the list view is losing focus

Thnx