# ListView.SelecctedItems is not showing selected items

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ListView.SelecctedItems shows 0 selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411620/listview-seleccteditems-shows-0-selected)

ok..Let me explain in better way My requirement is simple as it comes in windows my computer explorer which shows on left the tree node control with folders listing on the right side it shows respected files in it.. the similar way i have already the Tree node control and Listview control implemented. what i need is i will select one node and one object in list view then i click a button in another form it `Listview.Selecteditems` is showing 0. How to overcome? What i feel it showing 0 bcoz the list view is losing focus

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need earliest replay plz...help me

Comment: Earliest help will never get better results.Please provide the code what you have done.

Comment: Please, made your description some more brief. We dint get it actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [ListView.HideSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection.aspx) property to `false`. After that list view remain selected items if control looses focus.

Comment: in this case selected item will remain in highlighted after losing focus,but selected items shows 0 in this case also

Comment: No its not. You doing something wrong. Show your code it would be easier to understand what you missing.

Comment: The SelectedItems property will not contain any items if the property is accessed before the ListView handle is created.
So how to create handle?